# Any way to prevent dynamic allocation of a class?

Tags: c++, dynamic-allocation

I'm using a C++ base class and subclasses (let's call them A and B for the sake of clarity) in my embedded system.

It's time- and space-critical, so I really need it to be kind of minimal.

The compiler complains about lack of a virtual destructor, which I understand, because that can get you into trouble if you allocate a `B*`  and later delete the pointer as an instance of `A*`.

But I'm never going to allocate any instances of this class. Is there a way I can overload `operator new()` such that it compiles if there's no dynamic allocation of either class, but causes a compiler error if an end user tries to allocate new instances of A or B?

I'm looking for a similar approach to the common technique of "poisoning" automatic compiler copy constructors via private constructors. (e.g. http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/252214-Private-copy-constructor-and-private-operator-C)

Comment: The last part of your post makes me wonder if you're in need of a Singleton Pattern implementation.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: @Rycul: Thanks, they're not singletons, it's just that in small embedded systems we tend to do almost everything with static or stack allocation.

Comment: Just for curiosity. I don’t understand, why do you need a virtual destructor at all? Just because you are deriving doesn’t mean you need a virtual destructor. Do you have any other virtual function? How are you going to use such function if you are not going to use it dynamic memory in the first place?

Comment: @alfC: reread: "The compiler complains about lack of a virtual destructor."

Comment: p.s. keep your expectations low for responses to comments on questions that were asked many years ago

Comment: @JasonS, yes, but my guess is that the compiler complained because you had at least one virtual function already. no? and then my question was, why do you have virtual function in the first place in you never were going to use the object polymorphically.

Comment: I have no idea, it was 8 years ago... but I don't think I had any virtual functions. <strike>This was MS Visual C++, not sure which version but probably MSVC 2005</strike> oh right, it was an embedded system. Then it would have been TI's C2000 compiler. And no, I wasn't using virtual functions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can poison `operator new` in just the same way as you can a copy constructor. Just be sure not to poison placement new. A virtual destructor would still be a fine recommendation.

```
int main() {
    char data[sizeof(Derived)];
    if (condition)
        new (data) Derived();
    else
        new (data) Base();
    Base* ptr = reinterpret_cast<Base*>(&data[0]);
    ptr->~Base();
}
```

Comment: "A virtual destructor would still be a fine recommendation." -- it would be, except that w/o dynamic memory allocation it won't be used, and the memory costs in this one class are too high. (otherwise I'd just stick an empty virtual destructor there and be done with it.)

Comment: @Jason S: I wouldn't be so sure about that. Dynamic allocation does not always mean just the heap - it can also mean placement new. I could easily create an example which wouldn't use any dynamic memory allocation and still depended on a virtual destructor. If you absolutely can't use one, then poison placement new too.

Comment: do you know any "simple" cases that use placement new w/o dynamic memory allocation? This is a processor with relatively limited memory + no standard library (so STL isn't here; we're not using stacks or queues or things).

Comment: @Jason: Just posted one. I guess that if you know for sure that you're writing every line in your program, you could avoid it, or just poison placement new, but that code is undefined without a virtual destructor.

Comment: Well, I suppose I could make the destructor private also.

Comment: @Jason S: You'd need `protected` - else how can the Derived class call it in it's destructor

Comment: ah, true; good point. Although in this case the destructors are always empty, they're just there to prevent the compiler warning.

Comment: Technically this is UB, you should assign the result of the new-expression to `ptr`, or use `std::launder` .  Also the code snippet doesn't seem to have anything to do with the poisoning. I'm guessing it is meant to be a unit test that you didn't accidentally poison placement-new; maybe it'd be good to add some more explanatory text with the code sample

Answer (score 2):

```
class A
{
private:
    void *operator new(size_t);
    ...
};
```

The elipses are for the other overrides of `operator new` and the rest of the class.

Comment: or `void* operator new(size_t) = delete;`

Comment: I'm still able to do `char* addr = new char[sizeof(A)]; A* a = ::new (addr) A;`. How can I forbid all placement new operators as well?

Answer (score 0):

Just make operator new private