# C++: any way to prevent any instantiation of an abstract base class?

Tags: c++, class, abstract

Aside from having a pure virtual function, is there a way to prevent an instantiation of an abstract base class?

I can do this:

```
class BaseFoo
{
    virtual void blah() = 0;
};

class Foo : public BaseFoo
{
    virtual void blah() {}
};
```

but I'd like to avoid a vtable. (as per [my other question about virtual destructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271615/c-any-way-to-prevent-dynamic-allocation-of-a-class))

Microsoft ATL has ATL_NO_VTABLE to accomplish this (or at least I think that's what it does...)

Comment: Why exactly do you want to avoid a vtable? (And, if you're never going to use the fact that the method is virtual, why are you bothering with a base class?)\

Answer (score 39, accepted):

A really obvious way is to declare a protected constructor, and to declare public constructors in the non-abstract derived classes.

This of course shifts the burden of corectness to the derived classes, but at least the base class is protected.

Comment: Nice. But perhaps not "really obvious" ;-)

Comment: Well, obvious compared to the insane template hacks I was expecting people to post!

Answer (score 6):

You could make a protected constructor